# mtxrun can't locate '/usr/share/texmf-dist' not found, unknown 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua' scripts

Tags: context

Running Ubuntu 20.04, I can't get ConTeXt to work. I have the distro version and installed the latest version from the contextgarden. I have scoured the StackExchange for answer, to no avail.

If I do:

```
mtxrun --generate
```

I get:

```
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOLOC' set to '/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTODIR' set to '/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'SELFAUTOPARENT' set to '/opt/context/tex'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMFCNF' set to ''
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXMF' set to '/usr/share/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | resolving | variable 'TEXOS' set to 'texmf-linux-64'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | using configuration specification 'home:texmf/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf-dist/web2c;selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/home/coyu3/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/opt/context/tex/texmf-local/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-local/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/opt/context/tex/texmf-context/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-context/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/opt/context/tex/texmf-dist/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf-dist/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/opt/context/tex/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | found regular configuration file '/opt/context/tex/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | loading configuration file 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | locating list of '/usr/share/texmf-dist' (runtime) (tree:////usr/share/texmf-dist)
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'locators', how 'uri', handler 'tree', argument 'tree:////usr/share/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | trees | locator '/usr/share/texmf-dist' not found
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          |
mtxrun          | elapsed lua time: 0.018 seconds
```

and if I do:

```
context --version
```

I get:

```
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | configuration files already identified
resolvers       | resolving | loading configuration file 'selfautoparent:/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | locating list of '/usr/share/texmf-dist' (runtime) (tree:////usr/share/texmf-dist)
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'locators', how 'uri', handler 'tree', argument 'tree:////usr/share/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | trees | locator '/usr/share/texmf-dist' not found
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'scripts'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'scripts'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'scripts'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'scripts'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'mtx-context.lua' or 'mtx-mtx-context.lua'
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `type -a context` and `env | grep -i tex`?

Comment: Something is wrong in your settings….your mtxrun is located in /opt/context but TEXMF variable points to /usr/share/texmf

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. It seems I failed to uninstall ConTeXt from Ubuntu's repos. `type -a context` made that clear. 

I had to fiddle a little bit to get it to work from bash. It seems that in: `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc` path needs to be quotation marks: `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it deals with a conflict of installation options and is not really related to (La)TeX.

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt from Ubuntu's repositories remained installed and was conflicting with the manual installation. Now that I removed it and reinstalled ConTeXt,ConTeXt works to expectation.